# sed match dollar and single quote characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following string in my file:

```
"sequence A$_{0}$B$_{}$C$_{'0}$"
```

I want to move any single quotes that appear after a `$_{` to go before it, i.e.

```
"sequence A$_{0}$B$_{}$C'$_{0}$"
```

This is my sed command (using `#` as a delimiter) for just the part with the quote:

```
$ echo "$_{'0}$" | sed "s#$_{'#'\$_{#g"
'$_{0}$
```

So this works. However my text contains strings that shouldn't be matched, e.g.

```
$ echo "$_{0}$" | sed "s#$_{'#'\$_{#g"
/home/ppatest/texlive/2010/texmf{0}$`
```

I understand that `$_` gives the last argument of previous command. I checked:

```
$ echo $_
/home/ppatest/texlive/2010/texmf
```

But I don't understand why `$_{'` matches `"$_{0}$"`

Furthermore, I found that to prevent the Unix shell from interpreting the dollar sign as a shell variable, the script should be put in single quotes. But I can't do that as I am also matching on single quotes.

Comment: What's the output of `echo "$_{0}$"` ?

Comment: `echo "$_{0}$" ` will expand `$_` first and then append `{0}$` in it

Comment: `$_{` doesn't match `$_{0}$` as you are supposing. It only matches the `$_{` portion of it. The way `s#$_{'#'\$_{#g` works is that it is replacing *every* occurrence of `$_{'` with `'$_{` in each line passed to it. Have you tried putting that `sed` command in a shell script and found it to fail?

Comment: `$ echo $_{0}$`  
`/home/ppatest/texlive/2010/texmf{0}$`

Comment: Is not very clear what is your final goal. Could you provide a sample input and the consequent desired output?

Comment: This is my string "sequence A$_{}$B$_{}$C$_{'0}$D$_{0}$E$_{0}$F$_{0}$". And I like it to be "sequence A$_{}$B$_{}$C'$_{0}$D$_{0}$E$_{0}$F$_{0}$"

Comment: Update your question and add this comment there. In comments it is not clear what you mean

Comment: For your given input my answer works fine, I don't know what is missing here

Comment: @fedorqui i presume OP is still using double quotes for the echo which is expanding the `$_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach uses double quotes in `sed` to be able to handle the single quotes. However, as you can see, this produces the expansion of `$`, so that you can end up having broader problems.

What I recommend is to use a `sed` expression with single quotes. To match and replace single quotes, you need to close the leading `'`, the enclose the `'` within `"` and then open the expression again:

```
$ echo "he'llo" | sed 's#'"'"'#X#'
heXllo
```

In your case:

```
sed 's#$_{'"'"'#'"'"'$_{#g' file
```

This way, you keep using single quotes and prevent the expansion of `$`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello $_{'0}$ bye
$_{'0}$
yeah
$ sed 's#$_{'"'"'#'"'"'$_{#g' a
hello '$_{0}$ bye
'$_{0}$
yeah
```

Comment: I think they want it expanded

Comment: @JID it was a bit confusing at the end... but apparently, this is what the OP wanted, since he just marked as accepted.

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. Though I am still not sure why it works when using sed on a file but not when using echo.

Comment: @fedorqui my mistake , i thought they were trying to expand both, sorry :)

Comment: @HRaz what do you mean? As indicated in the comments to your question, please provide a sample input file and desired output. Otherwise it is a bit complicated to know what can be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "\$_{'0}\$" | sed "s#\(\$_{\)'#'\1#g"
```

- escape the `$` when using double quote
- use group avoiding several confusing `\$` when possible
- use double quote when simple quote are part of the pattern